# Spyder can not import plyfile

Tags: python

I have installed plyfile in the Scripts subdirectory of the Anaconda3 (I run Windows 10), using the pip3.  When I enter the command 
    import plyfile
in the Python 3.5 Shell, the command is executed without problems.
But when I move to Spyder and I enter the same command in the console I receive an error message:

```
   import plyfile
   Traceback (most recent call last):

   File "<ipython-input-3-db7ef797d821>", line 1, in <module>
   import plyfile

   ImportError: No module named 'plyfile'
```

I tried to add the path of the file to the environment using the Windows Commander and giving at the C:\ the command:

```
 sys.path.append(C:\Users\Alexandros_7\Downloads\plyfile-0.4)
```

but I received the error message:

```
 "sys.path.append" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file
```

I also tried the following commands from the console of Spyder:

```
  import sys
  sys.path.append("C:\\Users\\Alexandros\\Downloads\\plyfile")
```

These commands were executed without a problem.  Then I entered, import plyfile and I received the same error message -- i.e. that "No module named "plyfile"".

Could you please help me?

Comment: they have not the same path env, you can also add the environment in Spyder by sys.path.append(path to plyfile) and try it again

Comment: I tried but received the error message: ""sys.path.append" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"

Answer (score 0):

try give Spyder the same environment paths like Anaconda, in your case the path to the installed plyfile eg.:

your_module is located in: "C:\Users\Alexandros\your_module.py"

in Spyder:
lets add the located path to the system environment

```
import sys
sys.path.append("C:\Users\Alexandros\") #need string
```

lets import your module

```
import your_module
reload(your_module)
```

Comment: I still receive the same error message: "No module named "plyfile""

Comment: Code only answers are not very useful on their own. It would help if you could add some detail explaining how/why it answers the question.

Comment: Thank you for trying to guide me but I am afraid I do not understand.  What  your_module stands for?